# RabbitMQ message acked but not immediately included in queue

Tags: rabbitmq, automated-tests, spring-rabbit

I would like to write component tests of RabbitMQ listener. The test scenario is as follows:

- test places rabbit message to the queue and verifies it is confirmed by rabbit (publisher-returns=true, publisher-confirm-type=correlated)
- test periodically checks the Rabbit MQ `/api/queues/` admin endpoint until both `messages_ready` and `messages_unacknowledged` are zero

The intent is to wait and periodically checks until the processing queue is empty (i.e. both two above values are zero, meaning the message has already been processed by the listener).

However, the message is not immediately taken into the account by Rabbit MQ admin. One needs to wait up to several seconds until it is reported by the admin endpoint.

How can I solve my issue? Specifically, how can I distinguish between the following two states: the message has not yet been monitored by the rabbit admin, the message has already been processed by tested listener.

EDIT:
I set listener as follows

```
spring.rabbitmq.listener.simple.acknowledge-mode=auto
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-confirm-type=correlated
spring.rabbitmq.publisher-returns=true
```

and also set the publisher connection factory with the same settings (`publisher-confirm-type=correlated` and `publisher-returns=true`).

I am able to send a message from my test with some correlation data. The correlation data is immediately confirmed with `Ack` (meaning the publishing was successful), although the listener might not yet finished processing. However this still doesn't solve my issue.

How can I assure from the test that the message was processed by the listener?

Comment: The management plugin is, as you have discovered, not updated in real time. We use awaitility (or similar code) in tests to wait for the expected state using the rest API, and use countdown latches for the consumer side to indicate it has processed a message.

Comment: I was recommended to use approach equivalent to awaitility, however I am afraid I can run to false positives with my setup. My case is out of thread testing, cannot use countdown latches.
However I was directed to yet another approach - to use transactional channel. Will have a look at it.

Comment: Finally, I ended up with awaitility. The transaction channel is probably intended for another purposes (rollback already published message in case of some error on producer side while still in transaction).